# Django unit test is not finding any test

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-tests, django-3.2

I want to run a unit test on `test_models.py` the contents of the file is below:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class ModelTest(TestCase):
    def test_create_user_with_email_successful(self):
        email = 'superuser@super.com'
        password = '9876543210'
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            email=email,
            password=password
        )

        self.assertEqual(user.email, email)
        self.assertTrue(user.check_password(password))
```

after i run `python manage.py test` I get this:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

the file structure of my project is in the picture
[image: the file structure of my project]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right. I find the error. the folder `tests.py` does not contain any `__init__.py` file. thats why django cant locate test file. so it does not run the test.

At last adding `__init__.py` on test folder solved the problem